# Show a particular column data in form of buttons or links

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, stored-procedures

I have a query. I want to show a particular column data from a table in form of links. Suppose 5 rows and there in that column, I want to show 5 buttons or links.

Now I know how to bind in gridview or dropdown. But I'm totally unsure about this.

Any ideas will greatly help me.

Comment: I was trying to bind like we use logic to bind dropdown but no success

Comment: Have you tried to use DataList with ItemTemplate?

Comment: You can use a repeater by create a template as button and then bind the dataset or datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Hi basically you have two options that you can implement in many ways.

1. Set the data in the view model in your case create a property that display a collection of items based on the right column
2. In the view (ex: wpf) create a data template that display the row according the column